# IntelliJ IDEA: Open test result tab only on failure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Can I setup IntelliJ to open the "Run" tab with the test results only if a unit test fails and keep it hidden otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such setting as of IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.